# Create a slice using a tuple

Tags: python

Is there any way in python to use a tuple as the indices for a slice?
The following is not valid:

```
>>> a = range(20)
>>> b = (5, 12)   # my slice indices
>>> a[b]          # not valid
>>> a[slice(b)]   # not valid
>>> a[b[0]:b[1]] # is an awkward syntax
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
>>> b1, b2 = b
>>> a[b1:b2]      # looks a bit cleaner
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

It seems like a reasonably pythonic syntax so I am surprised that I can't do it.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can use Python's `*args` syntax for this:

```
>>> a = range(20)
>>> b = (5, 12)
>>> a[slice(*b)]
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

Basically, you're telling Python to unpack the tuple `b` into individual elements and pass each of those elements to the `slice()` function as individual arguments.

Answer (score 13):

How about `a[slice(*b)]`?

Is that sufficiently pythonic?

Comment: I had completely forgotten about python's `*args` syntax.  It would be more pythonic though if I could just write `a[*b]`.  Of course this would conflict with multi-dimensional arrays so the ordinary slicing syntax is still better.  Inclusion of the word slice is longer but probably far more clearly illustrates the purpose of the code.

Answer (score 5):

`slice` takes up to three arguments, but you are only giving it one with a tuple.  What you need to do is have python unpack it, like so:

```
a[slice(*b)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Only one tiny character is missing ;)

```
In [2]: a = range(20)

In [3]: b = (5, 12)

In [4]: a[slice(*b)]
Out[4]: [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11
```