# Advanced slicing with tuple using *args

Tags: python, slice

According to [Create a slice using a tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071264/create-a-slice-using-a-tuple), you can do it handy way:

```
>>> a = range(20)
>>> b = (5, 12)
>>> a[slice(*b)]
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

But what I need is advanced ones:

```
a[5:]
a[:12]
a[:]
a[-1]
a[-2:]
a[:-2]
a[::-1]
```

How to do it with tuple and `*args`?

```py
b = (5,:)
>>  File "<ipython-input-26-c4eae928199d>", line 1
>>    b = (5,:)
>>           ^
>>SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For options that you want to omit, replace it with `None`. Generally, if any option is omitted, it default to `None`.

So option like `slice(None, None, None)` is equivalent to `a[::]`. Also remember the `start` and `step` arguments default to `None`.

For. ex.

```
a[5:]  -> b=(5,None,None)
a[:12] -> b=(None,12)
a[:]   -> b=(None,None)
```

One thing to note here is, slicing is different from indexing. So you cannot use the `slice` built-in if you intend to index.