# How to select a "volume" from a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I know how to do this if I know the number of dimensions of the array when coding. I have seen [Select 'area' from a 2D array in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25609904/select-area-from-a-2d-array-in-python)

I am trying to figure out how to extract a "volume" from an any dimensional array.

I know how to slice arrays. `a[0: 10]` I know how to use that.
What I essentially want is a `[lower_bound: higher_bound]`. But the bounds are arrays that specify the locations in each dimension.

Comment: You could look at the indexing [doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html). TL;DR: you can use an ellipsis to denote any number of dimensions: `arr[..., 1:3]`

Answer (score 0):

Something like `0:2, 2:4` in the answer you linked is just a tuple of range objects. You can create such a tuple yourself using any code you want, and then do `a[slice(*t)]` ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071264/create-a-slice-using-a-tuple)) to slice with that tuple.

Comment: Yes this answers my problem